# how to make a sass mixin loop from array value(s)?

Tags: arrays, sass, each, mixins

I'm looking for some advice on my issue.

I have this mixin which works great..

```
@mixin theme-change($theme,$attr,$value) {
    .theme-#{$theme} & {
        #{$attr} : $value;
    }
}
```

which I then output like this..

```
@include theme-change('media','background-color', #242424);
```

---

But I need extend this mixin to handle multiple attributes, but all my attempt either result in compiling issues or just don't work.

See my closest attempt below (from this you can see what I'm trying to do) ..

```
@mixin theme-change($theme,$array) {
    .theme-#{$theme} & {

        @each $attr in $array {
            #{$attr};
        }

    }
}
```

This is how I'm outputting it..

```
@include theme-change('media',(
    'color: #ffffff',
    'border-color: #000000'
));
```

But the above just fails obviously, but you can see what I'm trying to do.

See I'm not sure if the array should be written in this format, but then obviously I need to declare the vars in the mixing...

```
@include theme-change('media',(
    'color' : #ffffff,
    'border-color' : #000000
));
```

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing css property:value into a mixins argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447477/passing-css-propertyvalue-into-a-mixins-argument)

Comment: Ahhh content might be a better solution. Did not realise this..