# Advanced SCSS/SASS mixin/function

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've made a pretty nice chaining effect, that I would love to turn into a mixin, or function, but I can't wrap my head around how to build it. Searched everywhere but I can't assemble the puzzle.

**The output should look like this**

```
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(3em);

  @keyframes moveUp {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(3em);
    } to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }

  .inview ~ & {
    animation: moveUp 1s forwards;

    @for $i from 1 through 20 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-delay: (0.1 * $i) + s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My current attempt (doesn't compile), looks like this:

```
    @mixin inviewChainAnimation($animationName, $from, $to, $duration, $delay, $count:20) {
        $from;

        @keyframes #{$animationName} {
            from {
                $from;
            }
            to {
                $to
            }
        }

        .inview ~ & {
            animation: #{$animationName} #{$duration} forwards;

            @for $i from 1 through #{$count} {
                &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                    animation-delay: (#{$delay} * $i) + s
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get two objects ($from and $to) passed through a function. Is that even possible?

Comment: Sorry, the marked answer do not solve the problem, because there are two properties to pass to the mixin. It can be solved by using of [SASS-maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps)

Comment: Thanks Rwam, that's correct that the question and duplicate question, isn't the same... I will try out SASS-maps. Thanks... :-)

Comment: @cimmanon: Once again, please take care when closing questions as duplicates, when in fact they are not.

Comment: @Matt Since when did you become an expert in Sass?

Comment: @RwamDev If you felt that there was another solution, you should have posted it on the question this question was marked as a duplicate of.  There was no need to flag this question to get it reopened by a mod.

Comment: @cimmanon You closed the question, so how would I post it except a comment? Back to topic: I will answer the question and will show, that the linked issue cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @RwamDev The question this was closed as a duplicate of wasn't closed.  The reason you couldn't have posted your answer there was what, exactly?  So congratulations for answering a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [SASS-maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) to render the declarations? For example:

```
$mapFrom: (opacity: 0, transform: translateY(3em));
$mapTo: (opacity: 1, transform: translateY(0));
```

And then in your mixin using of `@each` directive:

```
@each $key, $value in $from {
  #{$key}: #{$value};
}
```

But then there is another problem. If I try to parse the modified mixin, I get the following error:

```
Error: "20" is not an integer.
    on line 22 of test.scss, in `inviewChainAnimation'
    from line 34 of test.scss
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
@for $i from 1 through #{$count} {
```

To solve this change `#{count}` to `$count`. The same for `#{$delay}`. That's it. Here is the final working mixin:

```
@mixin inviewChainAnimation($animationName, $from, $to, $duration, $delay, $count: 20) {
  @each $key, $value in $from {
    #{$key}: #{$value};
  }

  @keyframes #{$animationName} {
    from {
      @each $key, $value in $from {
        #{$key}: #{$value};
      }
    }
    to {
      @each $key, $value in $to {
        #{$key}: #{$value};
      }
    }
  }

  .inview ~ & {
    animation: #{$animationName} #{$duration} forwards;

    @for $i from 1 through $count {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-delay: ($delay * $i) + s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use of the mixin:

```
.container {
  @include inviewChainAnimation('foo', $mapFrom, $mapTo, .15, .1);
}
```

If you have the need to pass only one set of css properties, you can use `@content` to simplify your mixin. See for an example at [Passing css property:value into a mixins argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14447477/1295622).